# problem with my magento admin

Tags: magento2, installation, wamp

I had tried installing Magento with WAMP and I did it all.

But the problem with my magento admin interface it is nothing there

[image]

and I think I have this error when it was being installed.

[image]

Can any one help me?

Comment: Take a look at your php error log. You can find it under WAMP installation folder. You can post the content of the file here in order to have more info regarding this.

Comment: Are you trying to install Magento 2.3 ?